# Unexpected result when printing a star pattern using php

Tags: php, logic

I am trying to print a star pattern using php. I am trying to print this:

```
    *
   **
  ***
 ****   
*****
```

my code:

```
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
    for($j=1; $j<=5; $j++){
        if($j>= (6-$i)){
            echo "*";
        } else {
            echo " ";
        }

    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

by doing this I should get above pattern but instead, I am getting this:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Anybody can tell me why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JonasW. i am sorry for that but i thought it is a general programming topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extra whitespace characters in HTML documents have no effect on the rendered output. If you look at the output page source, you will see that you are getting the correct result. Here are your options:

1) Send a `Content-Type: text/plain` header:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

Make sure to change your `<br>` tags to newline characters (`"\n"`, `"\r\n"`, or `PHP_EOL`)

2) Wrap what you have there with a `<pre>` tag

```
echo '<pre>';
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
    for($j=1; $j<=5; $j++){
        if($j>= (6-$i)){
            echo "*";
        } else {
            echo " ";
        }

    }
    echo "<br>";
}
echo '</pre>';
```

3) Use non-breaking spaces:

```
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
    for($j=1; $j<=5; $j++){
        if($j>= (6-$i)){
            echo "*";
        } else {
            echo "&nbsp;";
        }

    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

On another note, here's a one-liner that will do the same thing as what you're trying to do without the additional `for` loop and `if/else` statements:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
    echo str_pad(str_repeat('*', $i), 5, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

[Try it on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/R30Zo).

Comment: @RakeshKohali That's because it's using the "Content-Type: text/plain" header. The output HTML tags and entities are not parsed by your browser because it's telling your browser that it's in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I'd  be using `str_pad()`.  However if you need to use loops for your class assignment, then decrementing `$j` seems easier.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/9aY3S

```
for($i=1; $i<=5; ++$i){
    for($j=5; $j>0; --$j){
        echo $i < $j ? " " : "*";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

When rendering as html, you will need to use `&nbsp;` to show consecutive spaces and `<br>` for line breaks.  Or if your font is one that gives a different character width for spaces and asterisks, then you can sync the width by changing fonts or use `<span style="visibility:hidden">*</span>` for your non-asterisks.

Take your snippet to phptester.net to see how it is rendered as html.